# Display custom meta field in woocommerce orders report

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I want to display a custom meta field which exists in order into the report table and CSV report located at Woocommerce Analytics -> Orders.

For example in bellow picture, I want to add column in highlighted placed after Product(s) or at the end of the row.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This WooCommerce guide explains how to do that.

https://developer.woocommerce.com/2020/02/20/extending-wc-admin-reports/